# can't show the custom menu on window

Tags: tkinter

I have a custom menu class inherit from `Tkinter.Menu`. I use it in the root window like
this:

```
root = Tk()
menu = customMenu(root)
root.config(menu = menu)
mainloop()
```

Can anyone tells me what's wrong, please.

Comment: Nothing is wrong at first sight. What did you get? What did you expect?  (note: Python style advocate for CapWords class names)

Comment: Why do you think anything is wrong? Are you getting an error? If so, what error are you getting? If it's not crashing, what is it doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you showed us is perfectly fine, assuming your `customMenu` class properly inherits from the Tkinter `Menu` class. Here's a full working example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class CustomMenu(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = root
        self.file_menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.on_exit)
        self.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=self.file_menu)

class ExampleView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        root.configure(menu=CustomMenu(root))

        l = tk.Label(self, text="your widgets go here...", anchor="c")
        l.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class Controller(tk.Tk):
    def on_exit(self):
        self.destroy()

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = Controller()
    view = ExampleView(root)
    view.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```